# Makefile: either-or satisfy prerequisite

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here's relevant parts of a Makefile for a Python-based app. The goal is to make a rule where the presence of *either* `$pylib` or `$pylib-editable` satisfy a target dependency.

```makefile
pylib = $(VIRTUAL_ENV)/$(PY_SITEPACKAGES)/pylib/__init__.py
pylib-editable = $(VIRTUAL_ENV)/$(PY_SITEPACKAGES)/pylib.egg-link
pylib-any = $(or $(realpath $(pylib-editable)),$(pylib))

$(pylib-editable): requirements/.requirements.installed | $(VIRTUAL_ENV) vendor/pylib
    # this creates pylib.egg-link
    pip install --ignore-installed --no-deps -v -e vendor/pylib

.PHONY: pylib-editable
pylib-editable:
    -$(RM) $(pylib-editable)
    $(MAKE) $(pylib-editable)

.PHONY: pylib
pylib: $(pylib)

$(pylib): requirements/.main.installed vendor/pylib | $(VIRTUAL_ENV)
    # this creates pylib/__init__.py
    pip install --ignore-installed --no-deps -v vendor/pylib/

# Install Python (just release) dependencies
.PHONY: py-deps
py-deps: $(pylib-any) requirements/.main.installed | $(VIRTUAL_ENV)

# Install Python (development & release) py-deps
.PHONY: py-deps-dev
py-deps-dev: $(pylib-editable) py-deps requirements/.dev.installed
```

(other rules depend on `py-deps`/`py-deps-dev`)

The above `pylib-any` prerequisite seems to work if one of the `$pylib`/`$pylib-editable` files are found when `make` is run, but if there's nothing there and `py-deps-dev` is evaluated, then both `pylib-editable` and then `pylib` targets are executed. I presume this is because the `$(or ...)` is evaluated once during target parsing, rather than again after `pylib-editable` has been executed?

If it's built from nothing:

- via `py-deps` I want it to invoke `$pylib`
- via `py-deps-dev` I want to invoke `$pylib-editable`.

Is there a clean/elegant way to solve it? Maybe via double-colon rules?

Comment: What do you want it to do if neither `$(pylib)` nor `$(pylib-editable)` exists?

Comment: @Beta I clarified the question a bit, does that help?

Comment: Wouldn't a change in the dependency tree suffice? Instead of making `py-deps-dev` depend on `py-deps` just point it to `pylib`.